# Python string()[0] meaning

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def a4():
    l = []
    for i in range(100, 1000):
        for j in range(100, 1000):
            answer = str(i * j).split()[0]
            if len(answer) == 6:
                if answer[0] == answer[-1] and answer[1] == answer[-2] and answer[2] == answer[-3]:
                        l.append(i * j)
    print(max(l))
a4()
e
```

When i write the code without `[0]`, it won't work, so what does it mean

Comment: answer is of type string, you could also just cast to an int `int(...)`

Comment: In this case `answer = str(i * j).split()[0]`is a complicated way to write `answer = str(i * j)`. `split` splits on whitespaces and I don't see how `str(i * j)` could ever contain whitespaces in this code.

Comment: BTW, `if answer[0] == answer[-1] and answer[1] == answer[-2] and answer[2] == answer[-3]:` could be written as `if answer[0] == answer[-1] == answer[-2] == answer[-3]:`.

Comment: The .split() is a list creation method and you need the list index as in [0] to access the list content. plus: `str(int * int).split[0] == str(int * int) `always, using .split() in line 5 is just wasted code. Maybe just go instead with `answer = str(i *j)`?

Comment: There is no such thing as `string()[0]` in your code, as suggested by your title. `str().split()[0]` is entirely different.

Comment: @Matthias I think you've misread; it could be written as `if answer[:3] == answer[:-4:-1]:` which is a simplified way of checking `answer[:3] == answer[-3:][::-1]`.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the correction. Indeed I didn't see those minus signs. That was an `OutOfCoffeeError` on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `.split()` there is a list being returned. Putting a `[0]` after splitting means using the first element in the list that was returned from splitting.

Answer (score 0):

the split is giving you a list that each element is a token in the string  for example if you split the string "hi hi hi" it will return list that contain 3 element that each one of them is hi,
in your case your strung is multiplication of tow numbers it will always create 
a string with zero spaces so there is only one element in the list .
so i don't really need the split at all

Answer (score 0):

`split()` function change `str(i * j)` to a list, 
if you write the code without `[0]`, the len of this list is 1, so l is a empty list
max(l) while throw a ValueError。

there is no need to use split function, you can write `answer = str(i * j)`

```py
def a4():
    l = []
    for i in range(100, 1000):
        for j in range(100, 1000):
            answer = str(i * j)
            if len(answer) == 6:
                if answer[:3] == answer[3:][::-1]:
                        l.append(i * j)
    print(max(l))
```

or

```py
def a4():
    res = 0
    for i in range(100, 1000):
        for j in range(100, 1000):
            t = i * j
            if t > 100000:
                a, b = t // 1000, t % 1000
                if str(a) == str(b)[::-1]:
                    res = max(res, t)
    print(res)
```